# iOS phonegap: jquery sidr not working

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, sidr

I am new to phonegap. I wish to implement slide menu in phonegap. For this I am using `sidr` of jquery. When I use sidr in a separate htl file, it works.
Here's the code:

```
    <html>
 <head>
<!-- Your stuff -->

<!-- Include Sidr bundled CSS theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.sidr.dark.css">
</head>
<!-- Your stuff -->

<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include the Sidr JS -->
<script src="js/jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr">Toggle menu</a>

    <div id="sidr">
    <!-- Your content -->
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("sdf");
    $('#simple-menu').sidr();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This same code is not working in ios phonegap. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
        </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
              $('#simple-menu').click(function() {
                                alert("sdf");
                                return false;
                                });
              });

       </script>

<div id="sdf" class="topBar" align="left" style="padding-top:50px">
   <a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr">Toggle menu</a>
   </div>
   <div id="sidr">
       <!-- Your content -->
       <ul>
           <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
           <li class="active"><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
```

Even alert is not fired. Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?